# MySQL - avoid filesort

Tags: mysql

I stuck with filesort on my query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT o.job_offerid
FROM job_offer AS o
WHERE o.status = 1
ORDER BY o.sequence ASC, o.active_updated_when DESC, o.created DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This query uses right index, but stil uses filesort. Output from EXPLAIN:

```
select_type: SIMPLE
table: o
type: ref
possible_keys: status,status_sequence_active_updated_when_created   
key: status_sequence_active_updated_when_created
key_len: 4
ref: const
rows: 15153
Extra: Using where; Using filesort
```

Type of columns are:

status int(13), sequence int(13), active_updated_when (datetime), created (datetime)

Table MyISAM, MySQL version 5.6.21

I try to look at similar questions on stackoverflow, but without success.

Thank you

Edit (add table structure without other columns):

```
CREATE TABLE `job_offer` (
  `job_offerid` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sequence` int(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` int(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `active_updated_when` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`job_offerid`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `sequence` (`sequence`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `active_updated_when` (`active_updated_when`),
  KEY `status_sequence_active_updated_when_created` (`status`,`sequence`,`active_updated_when`, `created`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Any reason you want to avoid filesort?

Comment: Also, please provide create table statement with index structure.

Comment: It's because query is slow - 0.1 second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid filesort in this case.

Why? [Because of this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html):

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY
>
> [...]
>
> **You mix ASC and DESC**

Best you can do at this point if you want to completely avoid filesort is to rethink your `ORDER BY` clause. Is it really necessary to have all those 3 fields? Can you refactor your table to use less fields for sorting? Alternatively, can you change the meaning of one field to use only DESC (or only ASC) for all?

Comment: Yeap, that's it... Thank you, I'll try to figure out another way to load this data.